# getid3: download the full mp3 data from remote server

Tags: php, mp3, getid3

I'm using `getid3` to get the file size and the time duration from a remote URL. `getid3` does not work with remote URLs so the work-around is to download the mp3 to a temporary location, read the data and then delete it.

Code:

```
<?php $filename = tempnam('/tmp','getid3');
if (file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents('http://feeds.soundcloud.com/stream/336401044-scott-johnson-27-tms-1314-pm.mp3', false, null, 0, 32768))) {
if (require_once('id3/getid3.php')) {
$getID3 = new getID3;
$ThisFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($filename);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($ThisFileInfo, true).'</pre>';
}
unlink($filename);
};?>
```

My problem I have is that it only downloads the first 32768kb of the mp3 file and it doesn't show the correct filesize (shows as the max 32768) or the correct time duration of the file. If I increase the max size, the code will crash.

Is there a way to download either the full mp3 or find a way to get the appropriate header size without download the full file?

Comment: Which version of ID3 are you trying to get?  You probably need more than 32KB, but not much more.  Why is your code crashing over 32K?  I'd use cURL over `file_get_contents`, and you can make a range request from a well behaved server.

Comment: The latest version (1.9.5) and I have to use 20 mb in order to get the right filesize and time duration. I'm not familiar with cURL so can you provide an example?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: My problem is that my vagrant setup has a low MB set.  I tried it on my server and it was able to detect a file with 45MB and give complete data like file size and correct time duration. On my vagrant, It can only download 10MBs and give incomplete data.

Comment: You're keeping everything in memory, doing what you're doing.  If you use cURL and stream your result to disk (or request only the bytes you need), you'll save memory.

Comment: This is beyond my expertise in programming so I'll have to do more research on how to save to a disk temporary and then delete it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you can keep it in memory if you only request the chunks needed.  That is, try getting ID3v2 out of the first 512KB or so, and if it's not there, get the last 128KB of the file for ID3v1.  Check out doing range requests with cURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID3v1 tags are at the end of the file, not at the beginning.  Therefore, you won't be able to read them until you either download a chunk of the end of the file (with range requests done with cURL), or download the entire file.

If you want ID3v2, those will be at the beginning of the file.

Comment: There's no easy way to detect which ID3 version the mp3 is using?

Comment: @GregorySchultz Sure there is... try detecting ID3v2, and if it isn't supported, try ID3v1.